# Running Java program by a Java program

Tags: java, swing, jar, system.exit

I am making a program (3D Minesweeper) and I'm having problems with detecting the result. I tried separate Thread to wait for the result, but it doesn't work(just no). So I figured the simplest way would be having 2 separate programs (not a problem), where one runs the other (with args,1.problem) and gets the value returned by it's System.exit();(2.problem).
I've found some examples of solving the first problem, but not the second. Is there a proper way to do it, or do I have to write the result to a file or something?
BTW feel free to correct grammar, I'm just learning XD.

Comment: Put some code please.

Comment: Plus, define "doesn't work". Running threads did work in Java last time I checked :)

Comment: Your first solution (using a thread) will almost certainly end up being simpler, faster, and more maintainable than trying to do some crazy thing where you start up another whole process.  Show your code and we'll help you.

Comment: well, another Thread causes the games JFrame to show up empty and not respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `System.exec ()` to run the programs, then look at the return value of `waitFor ()` for the `Process`

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C dir");
int rc = p.waitFor ();
System.out.println ("Exit code is " + rc);
```

You can also look at the `exitValue ()` of the process, but you have to be sure the program has run to completion before this is reliable.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C dir");
p.waitFor (); // make sure we run to completion
System.out.println ("Exit code is " + p.exitValue ());
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I needed, when I get 15 rep you have an upvote XD

Comment: I can't figure out the proper command, file is in C:\Data\Patrik\Documents\Eclipse\Minesweeper3D named GameWindow.jar

Answer (score 0):

start the first program from the second and get exit value.

Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

int exitValue= myProcess.exitValue();